# Difference between 2>&1 > output.log and 2>&1 | tee output.log

Tags: shell, io-redirection, pipe

I wanted to know the difference between the following two commands

```
2>&1 > output.log
```

and

```
2>&1 | tee output.log
```

I saw one of my colleague use second option to redirect. I know what 2>&1 does, my only question is what is the purpose of using tee where a simple redirection ">" operator can be used?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Looking at the two commands separately:

```
utility 2>&1 >output.log
```

Here, since redirections are processed in a left-to-right manner, the standard error stream would first be redirected to wherever the standard output stream goes (possibly to the console), and then the standard output stream would be redirected to a file.  The standard error stream would *not* be redirected to that file.

The visible effect of this would be that you get what's produced on standard error on the screen and what's produced on standard output in the file.

```
utility 2>&1 | tee output.log
```

Here, you redirect standard error to the same place as the standard output stream.  This means that *both* streams will be piped to the `tee` utility as a single intermingled output stream, and that this standard output data will be saved to the given file by `tee`.  The data would additionally be reproduced by `tee` in the console (this is what `tee` does, it duplicates data streams).

Which ever one of these is used depends on what you'd like to achieve.

Note that you would not be able to reproduce the effect of the second pipeline with just `>` (as in `utility >output.log 2>&1`, which would save both standard output and error in the file by first redirecting standard output to the `output.log` file and then redirecting standard error to where standard output is now going).  You would need to use `tee` to get the data in the console as well as in the output file.

---

Additional notes:

The *visible* effect of the first command,

```
utility 2>&1 >output.log
```

would be the same as

```
utility >output.log
```

I.e., the standard output goes to the file and standard error goes to the console.

If a further processing step was added to the end of each of the above commands, there would be a big difference though:

```
utility 2>&1 >output.log | more_stuff

utility >output.log      | more_stuff
```

In the first pipeline, `more_stuff` would get what's originally the standard error stream from `utility` as its standard input data, while in the second pipeline, since it's only the resulting standard output stream that is ever sent across a pipe, the `more_stuff` part of the pipeline would get nothing to read on its standard input.

Comment: With the command "`utility 2>&1 | tee output.log`, do you mean to say that since 1 is being directed to tee, 2 is as well. Since tee duplicates the stream, the output is both displayed on the console as well as written to file? Hence the difference between `utility 2>&1 > output.log` and `utility 2>&1 | tee output.log` is `tee` in that it duplicates the stream. Would that be correct?

Comment: With the examples of `utility 2>&1 > output.log | more_stuff` and `utility >ouput.log` | more_stuff`, is the difference that `more_stuff` has the standard error output to the console as an input `more_stuff`? Since in the second example, there is no output to the the console, there is essentially no input to `more_stuff`? If yes, that isn't clear since the preceding paragraph you note that standard output goes to the file and standard error goes to the console.

Comment: @Motivated Your first comment seems correct to me, yes. As for the second comment: In the first command, `more_stuff` would receive what `utility` originally sent to its _error stream_ (but which was redirected to the standard output).  Not because it would end up on the console if `more_stuff` wasn't there, but because it's going to the _standard output stream_.  In the second command, `more_stuff` receives _nothing_ as there is no standard output from the left hand side of the pipeline.  The error stream from `utility` would still end up on the console in the 2nd command.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean that because the command `utility > output.log | more_stuff` does not result in an output in the standard output stream from a standard error point of view?

Comment: @Motivated Since the left hand side doesn't produce anything on standard output (it's redirected), no data will be sent over the pipe.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to clarify that when you say the left hand doesn't produce a result to standard output, it is because standard error isn't being redirected to standard output i.e. 2>&1 since the syntax is > output.log.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It'd be great if you could add a breakdown of what `utility >output.log 2>&1` does. I understand it outputs both stdout and stderr to the file, but not exactly why. You break down the other commands but not this one. Thanks.

Comment: @Max I have expanded one of the sentences in the first part of the answer to include "which would save both standard output and error in the file by first redirecting standard output to the `output.log` file and then redirecting standard error to where standard output is now going".

Answer (score 10):

First command will do the another task:

After

```
2>&1 > output.log
```

the old STDOUT will be saved (copied) in STDERR and then STDOUT will be redirected to file.

So, stdout will go to file and stderr will go to console.

And in

```
 2>&1 | tee output.log
```

both streams will be redirected to tee. Tee will duplicate any input to its stdout (the console in your case) and to file (`output.log`).

And there is another form of first:

```
    > output.log  2>&1
```

this will redirect both STDOUT and STDERR to the file.

Answer (score 4):

The former outputs only to the file.  The second outputs both to the file *and* to the screen.

Answer (score 4):

The reason for `2>&1 | tee` is to be able to capture both stdout and stderr to a log file and to see it on the screen at the same time.  This could be done as `>output.txt 2>&1 & tail -f` as well, but you wouldn't know when the backgrounded command terminated - is the program terminated or is it running with no output.  The `2>&1 | tee` was a common idiom for programmers.

Comment: Do you mean to say that 2>&1 > file.txt for example would not capture both stdout and stderr to file.txt?

Answer (score 0):

**Let's see some sample code first:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
main() 
{
// message 1, on stdout (using  printf)
printf("%s",          "message 1, on stdout (using  printf)\n");

// message 2, on stdout (using fprintf)
fprintf(stdout, "%s", "message 2, on stdout (using fprintf)\n");

// message 3, on stderr (using fprintf)
fprintf(stderr, "%s", "message 3, on stderr (using fprintf)\n");
}
```

**Lets compare the results:**
`./helloerror`
+ file: no message;    console: message 1,2,3;

`./helloerror >error.txt`
+ file: message 1,2;   console: message 3;

`./helloerror 2>&1 >error.txt`
+ file: message 1,2;   console: message 3;
+ same as ./helloerror >error.txt

`./helloerror >error.txt 2>&1`
+ file: message 3,1,2; console: no message;
+ note the order 3 is first, then 1, then 2

`./helloerror | tee error.txt 2>&1`
+ file: message 1,2;   console: message 3,1,2;
+ note the order 3 is first, then 1, then 2

`./helloerror 2>&1 | tee error.txt`
+ file: message 3,1,2; console: message 3,1,2;

**To use:**
`./helloerror >error.txt 2>&1`
*-> if one wants all(stdout+stderr) messages in file, but **not pinted on console***

`./helloerror 2>&1 | tee error.txt`
*-> if one wants all(stdout+stderr) messages in file and **printed on console***