# What is the difference between these two lines of code?

Tags: shell

I found this question in a test. what is the difference?

```
echo "data" | tee -a file.txt
echo "data" >> file.txt
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between 2>&1 > output.log and 2>&1 | tee output.log](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20469/difference-between-21-output-log-and-21-tee-output-log)

Comment: In this case, there is really no need to complicate it with other file descriptors like STDERR.

Answer (score 5):

Just try it out: the one with `tee` also prints the string to `stdout` (displays it on console output), not only to file.txt.

Answer (score 0):

They do the same thing, but the main usage of the `tee` command as it is explained in [this documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/tee) is to read from standard input and write to standard output and files, and it saves a lot of time in some cases. You can watch [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D_HhOq6sbZw) for more